# STM32 SPI not working as expected

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, spi, nucleo

I'm trying to enable the LED's on my MCP23S09 by writing to the GPIO register using SPI.

There are two chips on the board one is for the inputs and the other one is for the outputs, so the LED's.

I connected everything like I should, so I took CH2 low and connected the MOSI and SCK pin to my microcontroller.

I'm using a Nucleo STM32F411 in combination with the CubeMX software, So I'm trying to send data to the registers to enable functionality.

But unfortunately none of the LED's lit up on my IO Expander.

Next thing I tried was STM32duino, so I can write Arduino code for my board. But as far as I know this is just another layer on top of the HAL libraries.

To my suprise it worked just fine! It's the same piece of code, I just changed it a bit to work for Arduino.

But I still don't understand why it doesn't work when using the HAL libraries generated by CubeMX.

Arduino Code:

```
#include <SPI.h>

#define IODIR   0x00
#define IPOL    0x01
#define GPINTEN 0x02
#define DEFVAL    0x03
#define INTCON    0x04
#define IOCON   0x05
#define GPPU    0x06
#define INTF    0x07
#define INTCAP    0x08
#define GPIO    0x09
#define OLAT    0x0A

#define    OPCODEW    0x40
#define    OPCODER    0x41

// CS0 -> D2
const int slaveAPin = 2;

// CS1 -> D3
const int slaveBPin = 3;

// LED VAL
const uint8_t value = ~0x3F;


void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  // initialize SPI:
  SPI.begin();  //Initialize the SPI_1 port.
  SPI.setBitOrder(MSBFIRST); // Set the SPI_1 bit order

  SPI.setDataMode(SPI_MODE0); //Set the  SPI_1 data mode 0
  SPI.setClockDivider(SPI_CLOCK_DIV64);      

  pinMode (slaveAPin, OUTPUT); // First chip for inputs
  pinMode (slaveBPin, OUTPUT); // Second chip for outputs

  digitalWrite (slaveAPin, HIGH);
  digitalWrite (slaveBPin, HIGH);

}

void loop() {
    // configuration led-io-expander
    sendDataSPI(IOCON, 0x20);

    // all pins = output
    sendDataSPI(IODIR, 0x00);

    // Enable LEDS
    sendDataSPI(GPIO, value);
}


void sendDataSPI(uint8_t reg, uint8_t value){
    digitalWrite (slaveBPin, LOW); // Take slave-select low
    SPI.transfer(OPCODEW); // Send the MCP23S09 opcode, and write byte
    SPI.transfer(reg); // Send the register we want to write
    SPI.transfer(value); // Send the byte
    digitalWrite (slaveBPin, HIGH); // Take slave-select high
}
```

STM32 HAL:

```
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * File Name          : main.c
  * Description        : Main program body
  ******************************************************************************
  ** This notice applies to any and all portions of this file
  * that are not between comment pairs USER CODE BEGIN and
  * USER CODE END. Other portions of this file, whether 
  * inserted by the user or by software development tools
  * are owned by their respective copyright owners.
  *
  * COPYRIGHT(c) 2017 STMicroelectronics
  *
  * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without modification,
  * are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
  *   1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice,
  *      this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
  *   2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice,
  *      this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation
  *      and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
  *   3. Neither the name of STMicroelectronics nor the names of its contributors
  *      may be used to endorse or promote products derived from this software
  *      without specific prior written permission.
  *
  * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS"
  * AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE
  * IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE
  * DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT HOLDER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE
  * FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL
  * DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR
  * SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER
  * CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY,
  * OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE
  * OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"
#include "stm32f4xx_hal.h"

/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */

/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* USER CODE BEGIN Defines */
#define IODIR   0x00
#define IPOL    0x01
#define GPINTEN 0x02
#define DEFVAL    0x03
#define INTCON    0x04
#define IOCON   0x05
#define GPPU    0x06
#define INTF    0x07
#define INTCAP    0x08
#define GPIO    0x09
#define OLAT    0x0A

#define    OPCODEW      0x40
#define    OPCODER    0x41

#define SPI_TRANSFER_TIMEOUT    1000
/* USER CODE END Defines */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
SPI_HandleTypeDef hspi1;

UART_HandleTypeDef huart2;

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */
/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/

/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_SPI1_Init(void);
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void);
void sendDataSPI(uint8_t reg, uint8_t value);
int fgetc(FILE *f);
int fputc(int c, FILE *f);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */
/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

int main(void)
{       
    // LED VAL
    uint8_t value = 0x3F;

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration----------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_SPI1_Init();
  MX_USART2_UART_Init();


  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
  /* USER CODE END WHILE */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
        // configuration led-io-expander

        sendDataSPI(IOCON, 0x20);

        // all pins = output
        sendDataSPI(IODIR, 0x00);

        // Enable LEDS
        sendDataSPI(GPIO, value);

  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */

}

// REGISTER, VALUE
void sendDataSPI(uint8_t reg, uint8_t value){
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(CS1_GPIO_Port, CS1_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET); // Take slave-select low
        HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1,(uint8_t *)OPCODEW,sizeof(uint8_t),SPI_TRANSFER_TIMEOUT); // Send the MCP23S09 opcode, and write bit
        HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1,(uint8_t *)&reg,sizeof(uint8_t),SPI_TRANSFER_TIMEOUT); // Send the register we want to write
        HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1,(uint8_t *)&value,sizeof(uint8_t),SPI_TRANSFER_TIMEOUT); // Send the byte
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(CS1_GPIO_Port, CS1_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET); // Take slave-select high
}

int fputc(int c, FILE *f) {
    return (HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint8_t *)&c,1,HAL_MAX_DELAY));
}

int fgetc(FILE *f) {
    char ch;
    HAL_UART_Receive(&huart2,(uint8_t*)&ch,1,HAL_MAX_DELAY);
    return (ch);
}

/** System Clock Configuration
*/
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{

  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct;
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct;

    /**Configure the main internal regulator output voltage 
    */
  __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();

  __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1);

    /**Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
    */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = 16;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = 16;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 336;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV4;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = 4;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

    /**Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
    */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

    /**Configure the Systick interrupt time 
    */
  HAL_SYSTICK_Config(HAL_RCC_GetHCLKFreq()/1000);

    /**Configure the Systick 
    */
  HAL_SYSTICK_CLKSourceConfig(SYSTICK_CLKSOURCE_HCLK);

  /* SysTick_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(SysTick_IRQn, 0, 0);
}

/* SPI1 init function */
static void MX_SPI1_Init(void)
{
  /* SPI1 parameter configuration*/
  hspi1.Instance = SPI1;
  hspi1.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_MASTER;
  hspi1.Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES;
  hspi1.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;
  hspi1.Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_LOW;
  hspi1.Init.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_1EDGE;
  hspi1.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_SOFT;
  hspi1.Init.BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_64;
  hspi1.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;
  hspi1.Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;
  hspi1.Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
  hspi1.Init.CRCPolynomial = 10;
  if (HAL_SPI_Init(&hspi1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

}

/* USART2 init function */
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void)
{

  huart2.Instance = USART2;
  huart2.Init.BaudRate = 115200;
  huart2.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart2.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart2.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart2.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart2.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart2.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

}

/** Configure pins as 
        * Analog 
        * Input 
        * Output
        * EVENT_OUT
        * EXTI
*/
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{

  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOH_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(CS0_GPIO_Port, CS0_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(CS1_GPIO_Port, CS1_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : B1_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = B1_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_IT_FALLING;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(B1_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : CS0_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = CS0_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(CS0_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : CS1_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = CS1_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(CS1_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

}

/* USER CODE END 4 */
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not wait the SPI transfer to be completed before starting the next transmission in your `sendDataSPI` function. It should be modified like this:

```
void sendDataSPI(uint8_t reg, uint8_t value){
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(CS1_GPIO_Port, CS1_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET); // Take slave-select low

        HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1,(uint8_t *)OPCODEW,sizeof(uint8_t),SPI_TRANSFER_TIMEOUT); // Send the MCP23S09 opcode, and write bit
        while(HAL_SPI_GetState(&hspi1) != HAL_SPI_STATE_READY);

        HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1,(uint8_t *)&reg,sizeof(uint8_t),SPI_TRANSFER_TIMEOUT); // Send the register we want to write
        while(HAL_SPI_GetState(&hspi1) != HAL_SPI_STATE_READY);

        HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1,(uint8_t *)&value,sizeof(uint8_t),SPI_TRANSFER_TIMEOUT); // Send the byte
        while(HAL_SPI_GetState(&hspi1) != HAL_SPI_STATE_READY);

        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(CS1_GPIO_Port, CS1_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET); // Take slave-select high
}
```

Also this line just sends rubbish and not `0x40`.

```
HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1,(uint8_t *)OPCODEW,sizeof(uint8_t),SPI_TRANSFER_TIMEOUT); // Send the MCP23S09 opcode, and write bit
```

Notice that your are casting `OPCODEW` to a `uint8_t*` so actually you will pass the `0x40` as a pointer (pointing to some random memory) and not as the data.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it was indeed caused by OPCODEW pointing to the wrong address. The program seems to work fine without the         while(HAL_SPI_GetState(&hspi1) != HAL_SPI_STATE_READY); but I see, it is indeed important to wait for the transmission to complete.

Comment: @stickfigure4 Glad to hear it is working. This (`while(HAL_SPI_GetState(&hspi1) != HAL_SPI_STATE_READY);` ) must have been an early bug in the library then, which is now fixed.